# How to insert Secure Seal like McAfee and GoDaddy on Angular2 page?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

I have an Angular2 application using Webpack, etc. following this guide: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html

I would like to insert security seals on my pages (components) like McAfee and GoDaddy seals.

Those seals looks like that:

```
<span id="Seal"><script type="text/javascript" src="//tracedseals.starfieldtech.com/siteseal/get?nonononononononono></script></span>
```

I tried to use `required()` and `import` on my vendor.ts with no lucky.

Does anyone successfully inserted those security seals on Angular 2 application?

Many thanks.

**EDITED:**

As title says I would like to insert a seal into Angular 2 app.

Angular 2 **DO NOT ALLOW** to copy and paste the HTML tag provide buy GoDaddy, MacAfee, etc. because it has `<script>` tag on it.

As a workaround I just inserted the seal (it's just an img) on my website and made a `(click)` event on it.

Answer (score 1):

The github page you linked to in comments has this kind of a workaround:

.html

```
        <span id="siteseal">
        </span>
```

.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    ...
    const node = document.createElement( 'script' );
    node.src = 'https://seal.godaddy.com/getSeal?sealID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    node.type = 'text/javascript';
    node.async = true;
    document.getElementById( 'siteseal' ).appendChild( node );
}
```

It works for me although I suspect there should be a better way to handle this.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing angular specific here. Just add `html` to your page. You would get the HTML from the vendors e.g. for Godaddy here is the guide : https://au.godaddy.com/help/add-an-ssl-site-seal-to-my-site-4073

Comment: Angular2 don't allow to use script tag on HTML pages beside index.html for security reasons. Look at this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4903 . I could inject it using ElementRef but it's not safe. Look here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html